# Retrieving text from a closed Word Document in a Word Template (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-word

The VBA program I try to write has to retrieve information from a closed Word Document, based on the path name of that Document, preferably without showing the Document itself.

So:

1. Open file based on string (for example: "C:/Users.....target.docx")
2. Target information (text) in this Document
3. Copy this information to the currently opened Word Document (preferably keeping the formatting)

I have made some attempts to do this, but nothing has worked anything near satisfaction. Most examples I can find with google are based on using VBA in excel. Help is much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Basically your question is about item 4. so you can [remove the rest of the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26890253/edit)

Comment: I have modified the question, hopefully it's more clear this way. I have tried different thing but nothing came close to working. I have searched google extensively but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
Public Sub GetData()
   Dim x As Document
   Set x = Application.Documents.Open("E:\testing\test.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
   Dim data
   Set data = x.Content
   ' do something with the content or the document
   MsgBox data
   'close the document
   x.Close
   Set x = Nothing
End Sub
```